# How to test for harddisk damage preventing it from booting?

Tags: laptop, boot

I've experienced some problems with the booting of my laptop and I'm now unable to boot from the harddisk. In particular when booting I get this error message:

```
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

How can I check whether my harddisk is completely broken(and thus should be replaced) or if there is some "software" problem preventing the boot?

Note that booting from a Live USB I can see the partitions on the disk via:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Which make me think that the harddisk is not completely broken.

I must also mention that some times(seldomly) I could see some I/O disk errors when running Linux, and this make me think that, probably, the harddisk has always been a bit "damaged"

---

This is the full story of what happened and what I did:

> I have an Acer Aspire 5742G which had installed Kubuntu 12.04.2 and
>   Windows7 in dualboot. The windows installation often gave problems.
>   About 80% of the times I booted windows the computer, on subsequent
>   boots, would simply keep rebooting(something really similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124055/grub-boot-into-windows-7-breaks-grub-and-makes-system-unbootable)
>   question).
>
> Yesterday I booted on windows and the computer started rebooting.
>   After a forced shutdown the laptop started showing this error message:
>
> ```
> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
> ```
>
> I tried to recover grub multiple times, I also reinstalled kubuntu,
>   finally I wiped all the previous installations and installed kubuntu
>   on the whole disk, but nothing changed.
>
> I then tried to recover the windows installation using the recovery
>   disks, but right after starting the recovery I got this error message:
>
> ```
> Restore Failed--Error code 0x3ed (The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all required file system
> drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.)
> ```
>
> Searching on the net I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836330&page=2) post about the error and after
>   doing:
>
> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
> ```
>
> To wipe the MBR I was able to complete the recovery process.... to
>   absolutely no results. When I boot I still get the `No bootable device
>   ...` error.

Comment: What kind of recovery disks are you using? Does it boot with BIOS/MBR or UEFI? BTW, if the hard disk have nothing important left, I would try to re-initializing the partition table.

Comment: @AlvinWong It uses BIOS/MBR. The recovery disks where the ones I created right after installation(I don't rememeber if it was through an Acer program or if from Windows 7 utilities...). I was able to save all important information of the hard disk and I already removed/recreated/formatted the partitions multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smartctl` utility from [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) can help you to check and test your hard drive.

You can check your hard drive SMART values using:

```
# smartctl -A /dev/sda
```

or

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

But more importantly, you can test your hard drive using:

```
# smartctl -t [short,long] /dev/sda
```

And check the results:

```
# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```

You can also use the [`badblocks`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) utility but be careful as you can easily wipe all your data from the drive.

Comment: The first command shows a table where I can see that attribute `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` is `FAILING_NOW`. Also the `short` test reports a status of `Completed: unknown failure`. I've just launched the `long` test to see a more verbose explanation, even though I guess the only option is to replace the HD...